# Help! Do not know how to solve ODE using homogeneity of differential equations : $xydx+(2x^2+3y^2)dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What I did using exact equations[image]

My attempt at homogeneity"
[image]

What am I doing wrong here math friends? Why can't I separate these variables?

Answer (score 2):

Everything was fine until you've made a silly mistake. It should be 
 $$\large{v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{v}{2+3v^2}}$$ $$\large{x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{3v+3v^3}{2+3v^2}}$$
$$\large{\frac{2+3v^2}{3v+3v^3}}dv=-xdx$$

Comment: did I do it correctly with exact equations

Comment: @Maths2020: seems right until the very end, it should be $3=2x^2y+y^3$

Answer (score 0):

Integrating factor is $\mu=y^3$. Then solution of equation $$xydx+(2x^2+3y^2)dy=0$$ is
$$y^6+x^2y^4=C$$